# Deleting branch with repo abandon and git branch -D

Tags: git, git-repo

I am using git and [git-repo](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) for my project. I see when I try to delete my local branch which I am currently on using git command

```
git branch -D branch_name
```

It shows me error which I am expecting, as we can't delete current branch.

But if I use repo command

```
repo abandon branch_name
```

I am able to delete the current branch. So my question is what command is repo using internally to delete the branch?

Comment: If anyone is interested in doing research on this, you can find the source code for the `abandon` command at https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/subcmds/abandon.py

Answer (score 4):

The [`abandon.py` subcmd](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/subcmds/abandon.py) calls [project.AbandonBranch](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/project.py), which includes:

```py
head = self.work_git.GetHead()
if head == rev:
  # We can't destroy the branch while we are sitting
  # on it.  Switch to a detached HEAD.
  #
  head = all_refs[head]

  revid = self.GetRevisionId(all_refs)
  if head == revid:
    _lwrite(os.path.join(self.worktree, '.git', HEAD),
            '%s\n' % revid)
  else:
    self._Checkout(revid, quiet=True)
```

In other words, it makes sure to *not* be on the branch you are deleting, even if that mean setting up a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714) (by a checkout of a SHA1 '`revid`').